# Reversing a dependency tree into the original sentence

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm wondering if it is possible to convert a dependency parser such as

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
    (ADVP (RB also))
    (VP (VBZ likes)
      (S
        (VP (VBG eating)
          (NP (NN sausage)))))
```

into

`"My dog also likes eating sausage."`

with Standford CoreNLP or otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a `nltk.Tree`.

```py
from nltk import Tree

lisp = """(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
    (ADVP (RB also))
    (VP (VBZ likes)
      (S
        (VP (VBG eating)
          (NP (NN sausage)))))))"""

t = Tree.fromstring(lisp)

print(' '.join(t.leaves()))
```

Beware that your Lisp string needs two additional `)` at the end. Punctuation and spacing can be fixed with [Sacremoses](https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses).